# Why "is_zipfile" function of module "zipfile" always returns "false"?

Tags: python

As per the python documentation [`zipfile.is_zipfile(filename)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.is_zipfile) function returns True if filename is a valid ZIP file else False.

I have written my script as below and initially passed one argument and get "False" as result, But for other valid arguments also I am getting `False` all the time.

#### Script:

```
import zipfile

for filename in [ r'D:\Python_Programs\B1', r'D:\Python_Programs\B2', r'D:\Python_Programs\B1+B2\20130105\144145_1.zip', 'NEWS.txt']:
    print (filename, zipfile.is_zipfile(filename))
```

#### Result:

```
D:\Python_Programs\B1 False
D:\Python_Programs\B2 False
D:\Python_Programs\B1+B2\20130105\144145_1.zip False
NEWS.txt False
```

Can anyone help me out why I am getting False every time??

Comment: Does `D:\Python_Programs\B1+B2\20130105\144145_1.zip` exist? Is it readable? Is it a valid ZIP file?

Comment: @NPE: Yes this is a valid path and Zipfile. I am able to access this on windows by using WINRar or other utilities.

Comment: Just because the file has a `.zip` extension and WinRAR lets you open it, does not mean it is actually a ZIP. It could be a *different* compression format instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: So how can I check whether my file is actual zip OR not. And Is there anyway of creating an actual Zip and get it verified by is_zipfile() function?

Comment: @AshA: The zipfile module let's you create a zip. There are many other tools that create zip files, a quick google should help you there.

Comment: There's more than one "flavor" of zip file and it's possible you have one that is not supported by Python's `zipfile` module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for the Suggestion. I tried the code again on the Zip file created by a Standard tool and its working fine and giving "True". I think "zipfile" module only support standard zip files and not created by others methods. So problem is solved now but still I am not able to get the difference between my two Zips. :)

Comment: @martineau: Ya flavors are different but not able to get the difference between two. But problem is solved now.

Comment: Are the first two bytes of the file the ASCII characters `PK` (0x50 0x4B)?

Comment: @AshA: You can look at the `zipfile.py` source in your `...Python/Lib` folder and probably figure out what it checks and doesn't like about the format of your original zip file.

Comment: Yes The zip that I have created by standard tool have first two byte as "PK", While the second zip created by other method have first two byte as "Rar!". But what is the basic difference?

Comment: @AshA: Your `.zip` file lied. It's a [RAR compressed archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR) instead and should have used the `.rar` extension instead. The extension of a file can be changed, it is not *guaranteed* to be correct.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Right, By checking the properties I can get to know It's a "RAR compressed archive". Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As determined from the comments, `is_zipfile` is returning `False` because the file really isn't a zip file—it's a RAR file in disguise.  The file extension can be unwittingly changed.  WinRAR is able to deal with both zip and RAR files, so it can open the file regardless of its actual extension, but programs that only deal in zip files can't open it.

File types can usually be identified by examining the first several bytes of files and looking for various so-called magic constants.  This is exactly the purpose of the Unix utility [`file(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file).  A zip file is *usually* identified by the two magic bytes `PK` (more specifically, the four bytes 0x50 0x4B 0x74 0x08) at the beginning, although zip files have the special property that they're actually identified by a particular data structure at the *end* of the file.  The result of that is some interesting steganographic techniques such as [this trick](https://web.archive.org/web/20150925062822/https://gayhacker.wordpress.com/2009/04/03/well-well-well/).  But you won't see that too often in practice—almost all (if not all) standard zip tools create zip files that start with `PK`.

Comment: The link has been removed by the author. Do you have another source ? http://gayhacker.wordpress.com/2009/04/03/well-well-well/

Comment: @3nrique0: I've updated it with a link to an archive of that post on archive.org